# Form submitting to a OO-PHP Crud

Tags: php, mysql, oop, object

Trying to make a CRUD class in PHP. I'm basically trying to stick with making everything I do OO. My question is, how do I submit my form values to the class itself, I have a standard form that's just outputting to this file name .

However, I need it to refer to the right class... Cheers in advance for the help!

```
<?php 

require('connection/connection.php');

class Crud{
public function __construct(){

    $v_title = $_POST['v_id'];
    $v_title = $_POST['v_title'];
    $v_features = $_POST['v_features'];
    $yt_id = $_POST['yt_id'];
    $v_subject = $_POST['v_subject'];
    $taname = "videohubapp";

    echo $v_title;
}

protected static function Create($v_id, $v_title, $v_features, $yt_id, $v_subject){

    #Creates entries
    $query = $conn->prepare("INSERT INTO $taname (v_title, v_features, yt_id, v_subject) VALUES (:v_title, :v_features, yt_id, v_subject)");
    $query->bindParam(":v_title", $v_title);
    $query->bindParam(":v_features", $v_features);
    $query->bindParam(":yt_id", $yt_id);
    $query->bindParam(":v_subject", $v_subject);
    $query->execute();
}

public static function Read($v_id, $v_title, $v_features, $yt_id, $v_subject){

    #Reads database entries
    $query = $conn->prepare("SELECT * FROM $taname ORDER BY v_id");
    $query->setFetchMode(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
    while($row = $conn->fetch())
    {
        echo $row['v_id'] . "\n";
        echo $row['v_title'] . "\n";
        echo $row['v_features'] . "\n";
        echo $row['yt_id'] . "\n";
        echo $row['v_subject'] . "\n";
    }

}

protected static function Update($v_id, $v_title, $v_features, $yt_id, $v_subject){

    #Updates database entries
    $query = $conn->prepare("UPDATE $taname SET (v_title = :v_title, v_features = :v_features, yt_id = :yt_id, v_subject = :v_subject) WHERE v_id = :v_id");
    $query->bindParam(":v_id", $v_id);
    $query->bindParam(":v_title", $v_title);
    $query->bindParam(":v_features", $v_features);
    $query->bindParam(":yt_id", $yt_id);
    $query->bindParam(":v_subject", $v_subject);
    $query->execute();
}

protected static function Delete($v_id, $v_title, $v_features, $yt_id, $v_subject){

    #Delete entries from the database
    $query = $conn->prepare("DELETE FROM $taname WHERE v_id = :v_id");
    $query->bindParam(":v_id", $v_id);
    $query->execute();
}

public static function XMLWebService(){

    #XMLParse
    $query = $conn->prepare("SELECT * FROM $taname");
    $query->execute();

}

}

?>
```

Comment: What you want is a version of the [MVC pattern](http://oreilly.com/php/archive/mvc-intro.html).

Answer (score 0):

First take a look at [Model View Controller Pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MVC_Pattern).
Also in your class try using attributes and access them with `$this`

```
Class Crud{
 public $v_id,$v_title,$v_features,$yt_id,$v_subject,$taname; // all attributes

    public function __construct(){

    $this->v_title = $_POST['v_id'];
    $this->v_title = $_POST['v_title'];
    $this->v_features = $_POST['v_features'];
    $this->yt_id = $_POST['yt_id'];
    $this->v_subject = $_POST['v_subject'];
    $this->taname = "videohubapp";

    var_dump($this); // dump this object.
}
//.. rest of the code
```

when submitting the form something like this would work, depends though how you handle.

```
if(isset($_POST["submit"])){
 // a form submitted
 $MyCRUDObj = new CRUD(); // since you pass the values to the attributes of object from $_POST you don't need any parameters.
var_dump($MyCRUDObj); // dump form object and see what values attributes has.
}
```

a suggestion try to sanitize and validate form values based on how you want.
hope i helped

Comment: Did this reply solve your problem? Then accept it! See the FAQ for more details on that: http://stackoverflow.com/about